# Multi-Source Replication on MySQL

Tags: mysql, replication, synchronization, failover

I'm looking to to keep data from several tables in sync with each other across several MySQL servers (more than two). The current used version of MySQL is 5.5 and the operating system being used is Windows 7.

I've explored several options using additional addons such as tungsten replicator and galera cluster but both of these would if I'm not mistaken require cygwin or mingw to be installed along with other things like ruby which is not desired as this would be for a production environment.

Additionally I've looked at federated tables but I need the mysql server to be able to resync itself to the other tables if it went offline which would not occur with a federated table.

Is there a way to sync multiple tables across several servers with failover capability in MySQL?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto.html)?

Comment: I have but I believe what I need is a Multi-Master setup similar to the way MySQL-Cluster works in that each server is treated as a peer and writes can be done on any of the servers and it's propagated to all the other servers.

Comment: You might want to try MySQL Cluster Server which is a different product. Multi-Master is possible but comes with a whole host of caveats that can make it tricky to keep consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Since mysql is open source there is no supported automatic failover, also you have limited options in the setup. I strongly recommend the tungsten replicator. ruby, you need but definitely not cygwin.

http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/wiki/TRCBasicInstallation

and the data charmer's blogspot:

http://datacharmer.blogspot.co.il/

are a good starting point. If you need help instantly there is an irc room for the tungsten replicator. The only disadvantage is that you have to pay for the commercial version and consulting (superior services). After you've done the basic setup there is fan-in and fan-out replication. You can customize your setup according to what you specifically want and even create a customized complex setup.

I do not see installation as a problem, I have installed, uninstalled, setup and undone tungsten replication under several scenarios. Money would be the only problem if you are on a tight budget but you should be able to find your own way if you want the open-source option.